# When I reloade react App, it can't connect to the server

Tags: reactjs, url, server, react-router, reload

When I go to **About us** and reloade the site the server can't connect to the server

```
import React from 'react';
import AboutUsfrom './Assets/Pages/AboutUs';
import Home from "./Assets/Pages/Home"
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App" id="outer-container">
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/aboutUs" component={AboutUs} />

        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

The site works fine when I go to **About us** through navlink but not when I write **About us** URL in the address bar, neither when I reloade the App while I am on **About us**. (I guess it can't connect to the server)

It returned: **Not Found** "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Nginx or Apache? You have to route evertything to `index.html`.

Comment: @Jax-p Just how can i do that ?